# Requirements for mathematical proof

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question

Which mathematical subjects should one be proficient in before even attempting to begin with learning to prove mathematical statements?

Comment: None, I would say. Just start with attempt and they will present themselves one by one.

Comment: I don't know of a specific subject, but it's for sure of some advantage to know the mathematical proof methods (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof#Methods)

Answer (score 1):

None. Common sense logic is all you need for basic mathematical proofs.

Comment: Isn't for example algebra required at least?

Comment: No. Mathematical proofs existed before algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can try to write proofs at whatever level you're at, answering simple questions that come to mind as you study something.

However, it is helpful to have *read* some proofs before, so you have some idea what kind of argument counts as a proof. Other things that are always helpful are elementary algebra, a familiarity with the common types of proof (contradiction, contra positive, induction and so on), and a familiarity with the techniques relevant to the area you are studying (for example $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs in calculus).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the type of proof you're going for. But in all likeliness, if you can understand the statement you're trying to prove, odds are you are sufficiently skilled in the relevant area of mathematics to prove the statement.

Moreover, proper mathematical symbols and notation is not a must unless you plan to publish your work somewhere that requires it, say, a magazine or a textbook.

Comment: So, you think that if someone understands the statement of, say, the Goldbach conjecture or the Collatz conjecture, then that person is, in all likeliness, sufficiently skilled in Number Theory to prove them. Is that it?